# A priori justification for using a quartic regression

Tags: regression, modeling, feature-engineering, polynomial

I am reviewing some papers relating school performance to socio-economic background:

- http://archive.treasury.gov.au/documents/1421/HTML/docshell.asp?URL=05%20How%20much%20of%20the%20variation%20in%20Literacy%20and%20Numeracy%20can%20be%20explained%20by%20School%20Performance.htm
- [How should we treat under-performing schools? A regressiondiscontinuity analysis of school inspections in England](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmpo/publications/papers/2012/wp287.pdf)
- http://datatopics.worldbank.org/hnp/files/edstats/KHMimp09b.pdf

These papers use quartic regression to increase the explanatory power of their regression analysis, but do not appear to say why a quartic is a "natural" choice. Why would these authors have used a quartic relationship in particular? Of course this could be an orthodox choice for this particular area of study, but I can't immediately see that this is the case; I'm interested when quartic relationships should be investigated in general.

Comment: When deciding on what degree polynomial to use, most researchers simply keep adding polynomials until the next one isn't significant.  You can sort of think of polynomial expansions as "manual" flexible specifications representations, rather than automatic ones like those that involve penalization.

Comment: Hmm... if the variable they use it on is ordered categorical with 5 categories, it would be a somewhat natural choice. It doesn't look like that's the case though. It might just be a general "measure nonlinearity" thing that's grown up in one area, probably because of a single paper doing it and people copying that (and then others copying those papers).

Comment: Casio calculators have a `QUARTREG` but no `QUINTREG` function. But four seems like it would be a reasonable number of degrees of freedom to use in empirically modelling a non-linear relationship between predictor & response in many situations - allowing for a straightish curve, one with a single peak or trough, or one that flattens off, quite comfortably - so @Glen_b's probably right.

Comment: Why not try splines?   (two of the links does not work for me)